# How do i seperate my menu section form my main area on CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, web

I have to create a web layout where the title is a horizontal section at the top a vertical menu box below beside a main area box with both a content box and footer box inside. My problem is that I can't seem to get the menu box and main area box to separate. the menu bar overlaps the main area. any code that might fix this?

Comment: Need to see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this: **http://jsfiddle.net/byxwr1he/2/**

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    header
</div>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="sidePanel">
        side panel
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        main content
        <div id="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

#mainContainer {
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

#sidePanel {
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}

#main {
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 150px;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
```